# Joining Multidimensional Arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a query that returns thousands of arrays with contact info.  Each has a user id (IndvID) associated with it.  I need to join the arrays that have matching user ids into a multidimensional array.

So this:

```
Array
(
    [EmailID] => 1
    [IndvID] => 78
    [EmailType] => Business
    [Preferred] => false
    [Email] => theiremail@something.com
    [Listed] => true
    [!diffgr:id] => dbs71
    [!msdata:rowOrder] => 0
)
Array
(
    [EmailID] => 2
    [IndvID] => 78
    [EmailType] => Personal
    [Preferred] => true
    [Email] => theiremail@something.com
    [Listed] => true
    [!diffgr:id] => dbs72
    [!msdata:rowOrder] => 1
)
Array
(
    [EmailID] => 3
    [IndvID] => 85
    [EmailType] => Personal
    [Preferred] => true
    [Email] => theiremail@something.com
    [Listed] => true
    [!diffgr:id] => dbs73
    [!msdata:rowOrder] => 2
)
Array
(
    [EmailID] => 4
    [IndvID] => 86
    [EmailType] => Personal
    [Preferred] => true
    [Email] => theiremail@something.com
    [Listed] => true
    [!diffgr:id] => dbs74
    [!msdata:rowOrder] => 3
)
```

Becomes

```
   array[0](   
        Array[0]
        (
            [EmailID] => 1
            [IndvID] => 78
            [EmailType] => Business
            [Preferred] => false
            [Email] => theiremail@something.com
            [Listed] => true
            [!diffgr:id] => dbs71
            [!msdata:rowOrder] => 0
        )
        Array[1]
        (
            [EmailID] => 2
            [IndvID] => 78
            [EmailType] => Personal
            [Preferred] => true
            [Email] => theiremail@something.com
            [Listed] => true
            [!diffgr:id] => dbs72
            [!msdata:rowOrder] => 1
        )
    )
        Array[1]
        (
            [EmailID] => 3
            [IndvID] => 85
            [EmailType] => Personal
            [Preferred] => true
            [Email] => theiremail@something.com
            [Listed] => true
            [!diffgr:id] => dbs73
            [!msdata:rowOrder] => 2
        )
        Array[2]
        (
            [EmailID] => 4
            [IndvID] => 86
            [EmailType] => Personal
            [Preferred] => true
            [Email] => theiremail@something.com
            [Listed] => true
            [!diffgr:id] => dbs74
            [!msdata:rowOrder] => 3
        )
```

Matching each other with "IndvID"

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Can you please show your code for ist array?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: Can you change the query? It is what databases do best. 'order by IndvID' would be the end of the query.

Comment: You may use [Fox Filter](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1555-PHP-Filter-redundant-MySQL-database-query-results.html) and checkout `how2use.html` to decide if it suitable for you or not.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.  Sorry I wasn't clear (first question).  I'll make sure to include more info next time. AbraCadaver answer did the trick. I knew I was missing the simple solution.

Comment: @mgyura You don't even have to wait until next time!, you still can edit your question and add your attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way.  Creates the result with the value of `IndvID` as the key and then sub-arrays under.  Us the `array_values` if you want to reorder the main indexes:

```
$result = array();

foreach($array as $values) {
    $result[$values['IndvID']][] = $values;
}
// if you want to reset the keys
$result = array_values($result);
```

Comment: With answering questions where no effort is shown you are supporting such behaviour!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straight forward to do, I've made the key of the aggregated array the IndvID to make things even simpler, if that's not OK then let me know and I'll adjust the answer.

```
function add_to_array(array $array, & $aggregated_array)
{
    if ( ! isset($array['IndvID']))
        return false;

    $aggregated_array[$array['IndvID']][] = $array;
}

$aggregated_array = array();
// Run query here...
// I'm assuming mysqli here as it's what I mostly use, substitute as necessary
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    add_to_array($row, $aggregated_array);
}

print_r($aggregated_array);
```